# comma delimited string to array

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to take a string separated by commas and put it into an array. The issue is, it is pulling in table header garbage with the needed data as in the picture below: Is there a way I can do this that will not cause this issue or modify my code so that it is correct? Thanks in advance!

[image: Issue]

I have the following code:

```
Dim values As String = EmailList.Text.Trim
Dim list As New ArrayList    
list.AddRange(values.Split(","c))
ListBox.DataSource = list
ListBox.DataBind
```

Comment: Oh, and the text looks as follows:   name1,name2,name3,...

Comment: how can you make any change that will *not* modify the code?

Comment: That reads wrong, I meant "or a way to modify my code so that it is correct."

Comment: Is the garbage data the HTML information?  If so, you are going to have a bad time parsing that without using a 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the garbage data is consistent and always appears the way you display (with all email addresses within the same table cell), you can parse it by finding the location of the open cell tag and close cell tag using basic string functions:

```
    Dim intLocationOfOpenCellTag As Integer = strTest.LastIndexOf("<td>")
    Dim intLocationOfCloseCellTag As Integer = strTest.LastIndexOf("</td>")

    '+ 4 to account for four characters in <td>
    Dim strCleanData = strTest.Substring((intLocationOfOpenCellTag + 4), (intLocationOfCloseCellTag - (intLocationOfOpenCellTag + 4)))
```

If each address is in it's own html cell or row it will be more complicated than this.